# Why's it displaying Apache's default It Works! text when navigating to my project locally?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, debugging

I have two separate projects.  One runs using Laravel Sail which uses Docker Desktop (`mySecondApp.test`) and the other is a Codeigniter project running on `httpd` (`myFirstApp.test`).

The goal is to have both `httpd` and `nginx` turned on *and* able to access the two separate projects locally with no issues by navigating to `myFirstApp.test` and `mySecondApp.test`, respectively.

I've setup the reverse proxy so that both repos are on `127.0.0.1`.  The Laravel project running on Docker (`mySecondApp.test`) runs fine with turn on Docker.

But the Codeigniter project running on `httpd` gives the default apache message `It works!` when navigating to `myFirstApp.test` instead of displaying the project's true content. This shows that the reverse proxy is working as intended (correct me if I'm wrong).

I've verified that the project's `DocumentRoot` (the project's path on my local machine) in the `/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file is indeed correct.

I've ensured I've restarted `httpd` via `brew services restart httpd` and `sudo apachectl -k restart`.

I'm not sure what else to do. How can I get rid of the `It works!` default apache method when navigating to `myFirstApp.test` so that it can display the true content of the repo?

The reverse proxy (`myFirstApp.test.conf`) lives inside `/opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/servers` for `myFirstApp.test` and `mySecondApp.test`:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name myFirstApp.test;
    
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mySecondApp.test;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

This is what's inside `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1       myFirstApp.test
127.0.0.1       mySecondApp.test
```